# Does killing normal human enemies affect your ability to see the alternative ending?

Tags: metro-2033, metro-2033-redux

There's an alternative ending in Metro 2033, which unlocks when you're a "Good Person" by game's definition. This involves talking and listening to people, interacting with objects and other things. Each of such actions triggers a Moral Point.

Now does killing humans cause you to lose Moral Points? Do you need to purposefully avoid killing them?

Answer (score 1):

There are some choices regarding the killing of people which will affect which ending you get according to the guide I used they are the following this answer will only contain action needed to do in regard to not killing or killing characters for the full guide look [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/metro-2033/Secret_Ending):

> 2/Bridge: The box of childrens' toys in the traincar awards morality.
>   The traincar is on the first section of the bridge. Remember, enemies
>   are reduced to a trickle (if not completely eliminated) if you decide
>   to kill everything before moving on.
>
> 4/Frontline : Related to the [Invisible Man](http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Rescue_Ranger)(1) achievement. Completing
>   this whole level without killing anyone will increase your level of
>   empathy. Note this probably conflicts with the [Rescue Ranger](http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Rescue_Ranger)(2)
>   achievement, unless you've found some means of tranquilizing enemies
>   like that augmented wild man Adam Jensen in Deus Ex.
>
> 4/Black Station:  Successfully eavesdrop on the first two Nazi
>   sentries to sway your morality meter towards good. Use a stealth
>   approach for this. Killing these enemies with loud weapons alerts the
>   whole base.
>
> 4/Black Station:  Related to the [Merciful](http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Merciful)(3) achievement.
>   Completing this level without killing anyone will mark you as a good
>   guy.

down here are the achievements referred to in the quoted piece:

(1) **Invisible Man** is an achievement/trophy in Metro 2033 and Metro 2033 Redux, awarded for not killing a single enemy on the level Front Line. Front Line is a very large level with many enemies but with enough restraint and caution, players can avoid all combat.

(2) **Rescue Ranger** is an achievement/trophy in Metro 2033 and Metro 2033 Redux , awarded for rescuing the Red prisoners from the Nazis in Frontline. The prisoners are found near the end of the level in a Nazi camp. Going for this achievement/trophy will render Hedge-hopper unobtainable as after the prisoners are freed they will be unkillable thus the other achievements have to be done on other separate playthroughs.

(3) **Merciful** is an achievement/trophy in Metro 2033 and Metro 2033 Redux, awarded  for not killing or knocking out a single Nazi soldier on the level Black Station. This is quite a bit easier said than done as any Nazi will immediately fire upon the player if detected